# vim: replace word with first word of line

Tags: vim

**Problem**
I have a file which looks like this:

> word= something something aaa something aaa
>   word2= something something aaa something aaa
>   word3= something something aaa something aaa

Note that the "something " are not necessarily the same word everywhere. Also "something " and "aaa " are not necessarily separated by white spaces.

**Question**
I would like to replace all occurrences of "aaa" with the first word of the line within vim. The output should look like:

> word= something something word something word
>   word2= something something word2 something word2
>   word3= something something word3 something word3

So far I have mainly looked into the search and replace syntax of vim, because that is what I am most familiar with.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a solution entirely with regex, I suggest this:

```
:%s/\v%(^([^=]+).*)@<=aaa/\1/g
```

This works with a look behind (`\@<=`) which has zero width. The `\v` at
the start  of the regex is  just to simplify escaping  by enabling "very
magic" mode (see `:h \v`). The expression itself:

```
%(^([^=]+).*)@<=aaa
```

The look behind operates  with the first group. The `%()`  form is a non
capturing group (a bit faster, and won't  count as a numbered one in the
substitution). The inner  group captures anything not a  equal sign, and
after this group, anything is matched (`.*`). All of this is not counted
in the regex,  what is really matched  is the `aaa`, however  it is only
matched if  preceded by those  conditions. Of  course it is  preceded by
them, but the goal is to capture the first word.

This `aaa` is then substituted by  the captured group, multiple times in
a line (`g` flag) and in all lines (`%` range).

Answer (score 2):

This `:s` command works for your example:

```
%s/\<aaa\>/\=substitute(getline('.'),'^[^=]*\zs=.*','','')/g
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but I think you can make it simpler by using `\=matchstr(getline('.'),'^[^=]*')` instead of the `substitute()`